# NextJS & ChakraUI Show alert dialog when user leaves page with unsaved changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, dialog, chakra-ui

I have a nextJS records page. If the user has made changes to the inputs and then clicks a link or goes back, I want a dialog box to show up and ask them if they want to leave the page. If they click 'NO' the dialog should close and the user must stay in the page. If they click 'YES' they should continue moving to the route they initially selected.

I have already implemented something but I have 2 problems.

- The onOpen function that opens the Dialog is not triggered although the console.log prints out the message normally which means that my logic is correct.
- How can I ensure that if the user clicks YES the user will land to the page that initially chose (e.g. he clicks on the "settings" link and after the dialog the app goes to /settings)

Here is the code:

```
import {
  Box,
  Grid,
  GridItem,
  Input,
  Flex,
  Button,
  useColorModeValue,
} from "@chakra-ui/react";
import {
  AlertDialog,
  AlertDialogBody,
  AlertDialogFooter,
  AlertDialogHeader,
  AlertDialogContent,
  AlertDialogOverlay,
  useDisclosure,
} from "@chakra-ui/react";
import PasswordEditor from "@/components/PasswordEditor";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { postMethod, updateMethod } from "@/helpers/services";
import TopNav from "./TopNav";
import showMsg from "@/helpers/showMsg";
import { IRecordEditingProps, IRecordEditData } from "@/types/components";
import deepEqual from "deep-equal";

const RecordEditing: React.FC<IRecordEditingProps> = ({
  type,
  record,
  user,
}) => {
  const [recordObj, setRecordObj] = useState<IRecordEditData>(record);
  const [password, setPassword] = useState<string>(record.password);
  const title = type === "new" ? "New Record" : "Edit Record";
  const router = useRouter();
  const { recordId } = router.query;
  const { isOpen, onOpen, onClose } = useDisclosure();
  const cancelRef = useRef();
  const buttonBg = useColorModeValue("#dbdbdb", "#2a2c38");

  const handleInputChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setRecordObj((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [e.target.id]: e.target.value,
    }));
  };

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    if (type === "new") {
      postMethod(`/api/user/${user.id}/records`, {
        ...recordObj,
        password,
      })
        .then(() => router.push("/"))
        .catch(() => showMsg("Something went wrong", { type: "error" }));
    } else {
      updateMethod(`/api/user/${user.id}/records/${recordId}`, {
        ...recordObj,
        password,
      })
        .then(() => router.push("/"))
        .catch(() => showMsg("Something went wrong", { type: "error" }));
    }
  };

  const openDialog = () => onOpen();

  useEffect(() => {
    const checkForChanges = (): void => {
      if (!deepEqual(recordObj, record)) {
        openDialog();
        console.log("Warning for changes!!!!!!!!!!");
      }
    };

    router.events.on("routeChangeStart", checkForChanges);

    return () => {
      console.log("unmounting component...");
      router.events.off("routeChangeStart", checkForChanges);
    };
  }, [recordObj, record]);

  return (
    <Box py="60px">
      <TopNav title={title} type="backAndTitle" />
      <Box>
        <Grid gridTemplateColumns="3fr 6fr" gap="10px" py="10px">
          <GridItem w="100%" h="10">
            <Flex align="center" h="100%">
              Title
            </Flex>
          </GridItem>
          <GridItem w="100%" h="10">
            <Input
              id="title"
              value={recordObj.title}
              placeholder="Record title"
              onChange={handleInputChange}
              _focusVisible={{ border: "2px solid", borderColor: "teal.200" }}
            />
          </GridItem>
          <GridItem w="100%" h="10">
            <Flex align="center" h="100%">
              Url
            </Flex>
          </GridItem>
          <GridItem w="100%" h="10">
            <Input
              id="url"
              value={recordObj.url}
              placeholder="Website url (optional)"
              onChange={handleInputChange}
              _focusVisible={{ border: "2px solid", borderColor: "teal.200" }}
            />
          </GridItem>
          <GridItem w="100%" h="10">
            <Flex align="center" h="100%">
              Username
            </Flex>
          </GridItem>
          <GridItem w="100%" h="10">
            <Input
              id="username"
              value={recordObj.username}
              placeholder="Username or email"
              onChange={handleInputChange}
              _focusVisible={{ border: "2px solid", borderColor: "teal.200" }}
            />
          </GridItem>
        </Grid>
      </Box>
      <PasswordEditor password={password} setPassword={setPassword} />
      <Box mt="20px">
        <Button
          type="submit"
          w="100%"
          background={buttonBg}
          _focus={{ background: buttonBg }}
          onClick={handleSubmit}
        >
          Save Record
        </Button>
      </Box>
      <AlertDialog
        motionPreset="slideInBottom"
        leastDestructiveRef={cancelRef}
        onClose={onClose}
        isOpen={isOpen}
        isCentered
      >
        <AlertDialogOverlay />

        <AlertDialogContent>
          <AlertDialogHeader>
            Are you sure you want to leave this page?
          </AlertDialogHeader>
          <AlertDialogBody>
            You have unsaved changes. Are you sure you want to leave this page?
            Unsaved changes will be lost!
          </AlertDialogBody>
          <AlertDialogFooter>
            <Button ref={cancelRef} onClick={onClose}>
              No
            </Button>
            <Button
              onClick={() =>
                console.log("Leave page and go to the clicked route")
              }
              colorScheme="red"
              ml={3}
            >
              Yes
            </Button>
          </AlertDialogFooter>
        </AlertDialogContent>
      </AlertDialog>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default RecordEditing;
```

Comment: You are using useEffect and I dont see a 'use client' directive on this. You need to break out the server and client side features here and perhaps make a client side component for the dialog box. I'm assuming you are using next 13/app routing.

Comment: did you figure this out?

Comment: I added the solution here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following hook to handle the case:

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { useCallback, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

const errorMessage = "Please ignore this error.";

const throwFakeErrorToFoolNextRouter = () => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-throw-literal
  throw errorMessage;
};

const rejectionHandler = (event: PromiseRejectionEvent) => {
  if (event.reason === errorMessage) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
};
interface Props {
  shouldStopNavigation: boolean;
  onNavigate: () => void;
}

const useNavigationObserver = ({ shouldStopNavigation, onNavigate }: Props) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const currentPath = router.asPath;
  const nextPath = useRef("");
  const navigationConfirmed = useRef(false);

  const killRouterEvent = useCallback(() => {
    router.events.emit("routeChangeError", "", "", { shallow: false });
    throwFakeErrorToFoolNextRouter();
  }, [router]);

  useEffect(() => {
    navigationConfirmed.current = false;

    const onRouteChange = (url: string) => {
      if (currentPath !== url) {
        window.history.pushState(null, "", router.basePath + currentPath);
      }

      if (
        shouldStopNavigation &&
        url !== currentPath &&
        !navigationConfirmed.current
      ) {
        nextPath.current = url.replace(router.basePath, "");
        onNavigate();
        killRouterEvent();
      }
    };

    router.events.on("routeChangeStart", onRouteChange);
    window.addEventListener("unhandledrejection", rejectionHandler);

    return () => {
      router.events.off("routeChangeStart", onRouteChange);
      window.removeEventListener("unhandledrejection", rejectionHandler);
    };
  }, [
    currentPath,
    killRouterEvent,
    onNavigate,
    router.basePath,
    router.events,
    shouldStopNavigation,
  ]);

  const confirmNavigation = () => {
    navigationConfirmed.current = true;
    router.push(nextPath.current);
  };

  return confirmNavigation;
};

export { useNavigationObserver };
```

And this is how I added it to the component

```
import { useState } from "react";
import {
  Box,
  Grid,
  GridItem,
  Input,
  Flex,
  Button,
  useColorModeValue,
  useDisclosure,
} from "@chakra-ui/react";
import PasswordEditor from "@/components/PasswordEditor";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { postMethod, updateMethod } from "@/helpers/services";
import TopNav from "./TopNav";
import AlertModal from "./AlertModal";
import showMsg from "@/helpers/showMsg";
import isDeepEqual from "deep-equal";
import { IRecordEditingProps, IRecordEditData } from "@/types/components";
import { useNavigationObserver } from "@/hooks/useNavigationObserver";

const RecordEditing: React.FC<IRecordEditingProps> = ({
  type,
  record,
  user,
}) => {
  const [recordObj, setRecordObj] = useState<IRecordEditData>(record);
  const [password, setPassword] = useState<string>(record.password);
  const [isDirty, setIsDirty] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const defaultRecord = { ...record, password };
  const title = type === "new" ? "New Record" : "Edit Record";
  const router = useRouter();
  const { recordId } = router.query;
  const buttonBg = useColorModeValue("#dbdbdb", "#2a2c38");
  const { isOpen, onOpen, onClose } = useDisclosure();
  const navigate = useNavigationObserver({
    shouldStopNavigation: isDirty,
    onNavigate: () => onOpen(),
  });

  const setDirtyInputs = () => {
    if (!isDeepEqual(defaultRecord, { ...recordObj, password })) {
      setIsDirty(true);
    } else {
      setIsDirty(false);
    }
  };
  const handleInputChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setRecordObj((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [e.target.id]: e.target.value,
    }));
    setDirtyInputs();
  };

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    setIsDirty(false);
    if (type === "new") {
      postMethod(`/api/user/${user.id}/records`, {
        ...recordObj,
        password,
      })
        .then(() => router.push("/"))
        .then(() => showMsg("Record saved", { type: "success" }))
        .catch(() => showMsg("Something went wrong", { type: "error" }));
    } else {
      updateMethod(`/api/user/${user.id}/records/${recordId}`, {
        ...recordObj,
        password,
      })
        .then(() => router.push("/"))
        .then(() => showMsg("Record updated", { type: "success" }))
        .catch(() => showMsg("Something went wrong", { type: "error" }));
    }
  };

  return (
    <Box py="60px">
      <TopNav title={title} type="backAndTitle" />
      <Box>
        <Grid gridTemplateColumns="3fr 6fr" gap="10px" py="10px">
          <GridItem w="100%" h="10">
            <Flex align="center" h="100%">
              Title
            </Flex>
          </GridItem>
          <GridItem w="100%" h="10">
            <Input
              id="title"
              value={recordObj.title}
              placeholder="Record title"
              onChange={handleInputChange}
              _focusVisible={{ border: "2px solid", borderColor: "teal.200" }}
            />
          </GridItem>
          <GridItem w="100%" h="10">
            <Flex align="center" h="100%">
              Url
            </Flex>
          </GridItem>
          <GridItem w="100%" h="10">
            <Input
              id="url"
              value={recordObj.url}
              placeholder="Website url (optional)"
              onChange={handleInputChange}
              _focusVisible={{ border: "2px solid", borderColor: "teal.200" }}
            />
          </GridItem>
          <GridItem w="100%" h="10">
            <Flex align="center" h="100%">
              Username
            </Flex>
          </GridItem>
          <GridItem w="100%" h="10">
            <Input
              id="username"
              value={recordObj.username}
              placeholder="Username or email"
              onChange={handleInputChange}
              _focusVisible={{ border: "2px solid", borderColor: "teal.200" }}
            />
          </GridItem>
        </Grid>
      </Box>
      <PasswordEditor password={password} setPassword={setPassword} />
      <Box mt="20px">
        <Button
          type="submit"
          w="100%"
          background={buttonBg}
          _focus={{ background: buttonBg }}
          onClick={handleSubmit}
        >
          Save Record
        </Button>
      </Box>
      <AlertModal
        type="leave"
        onClose={onClose}
        isOpen={isOpen}
        callBackAction={navigate}
      />
    </Box>
  );
};

export default RecordEditing;
```

Comment: This no longer works in Next.js 13/14 app dir. They removed the router events so we can no longer listen and block routing. https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/41934